# Laravel irazasyed telegram-bot-sdk

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot

It is my second bot

```
$dream =new Api(config('telegram.bots.mySecondBot.token'));
```

Now I want to update my second bot commandHandler

```
$update = $dream->commandsHandler(true);
```

then I want to call command

```
$dream->triggerCommand('start', $update);
```

But it does not call command pls give advice...

Comment: Please provide other informations and the error you get.

Comment: Are the two bots running in the same Laravel installation? Have you checked the value of config('telegram.bots.mySecondBot.token')? Did you regenerate the configuration cache?

Comment: yes it will work the same Laravel installation , yes checked config , I think commandsHandler don't work